# Convert NSNumber (double) value into time

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

i try to convert a value like "898.171813964844" into 00:17:02 (hh:mm:ss).

How can this be done in objective c?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could use simple arithmatic, but I am not seeing how 898.171813964844 would be 00:17:02.  What does the float refer to?

Comment: Hey, in ruby i simple do Time.at(time - 3600).strftime("%H:%M:%S") and get the correct result. (time is the float value)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Final solution:

```
NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([online_time doubleValue] - 3600)];
NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];    
NSDate *online = [NSDate date];
online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

Comment: Why do I get something like 8 hours 1 minutes and 34 seconds when I have the value 94.000 in my interval?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Ben - this is likely because your timezone is +8 hours.  Try setting the timezone to GMT `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];`

Comment: This solution is not the best. I just moved from Slovakia to Buenos Aires and even I used the trick mention by @Ben I still get wrong conversion. Generally this works in all cases when your "Settings/Date&Time/Set Automatically" is off in iPhone.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you are just interested in hours, minutes and seconds and that the input value is less or equal 86400 you could do something like this:

```
NSNumber *theDouble = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:898.171813964844];

int inputSeconds = [theDouble intValue];
int hours =  inputSeconds / 3600;
int minutes = ( inputSeconds - hours * 3600 ) / 60; 
int seconds = inputSeconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60; 

NSString *theTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d:%.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

Answer (score 3):

I know the answer has already been accepted, but here is my response using NSDateFormatter and taking into account timezone (to your timezone hours [eg. GMT+4] being unexpectedly added @Ben)

```
    NSTimeInterval intervalValue = 898.171813964844;
    NSDateFormatter *hmsFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [hmsFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    [hmsFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSLog(@"formatted date: %@", [hmsFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:intervalValue]]);
```

*[side note]* @phx: assuming 898.171813964844 is in seconds, this would represent 00:14:58 not 00:17:02.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your NSNumber value to a NSTimeInterval with `-doubleValue`
2. Convert your NSTimeInterval value to a NSDate with `+dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:`
3. Convert your NSDate to a NSString with `-descriptionWithCalendarFormat:timeZone:locale:`

Comment: NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue]; 
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval]; 
NSString *value = [date descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%I:%M:%S" timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] locale:nil]; 

like this? But i get: 
warning NSDate may not respond to -descriptionWithCalendarFormat....

Comment: The non-deprecated way (or iPhone SDK way) of converting an NSDate to a string is to use an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Also, are you trying to convert the number into an absolute time (i.e., is it a timestamp?) or units (i.e., is the number just an amount of seconds?)?

Comment: Nevermind, I missed your comment up above. Use an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: -descriptionWithCalendarFormat... is not available on iPhone. Use an NSDateFormatter instead, as suggested by Wevah.