# convert float to NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm wondering, in `objective-c`, how can I convert a `float` type primative number to `NSTimeInterval`?

The `float` type value represents the number of seconds in my case

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259028/convert-nsnumber-double-value-into-time

Comment: Just cast to a `double`.  What's the problem?  e.g. `NSTimeInterval interval = (NSTimeInterval)myFloatyTime;`.  You don't even need the cast.

Comment: @Avi, thanks, I don't know that, so I ask. Now I know :)

Comment: You shouldn't be using float at all unless you have a very good reason, but you should be using double. float has very low precision. Use double to start with.

Comment: in ObjC: `typedef double NSTimeInterval;` or in Swift: `public typealias NSTimeInterval = Double`... so... how to convert a `float` to `double`...?

Answer (score 3):

NSTimeInterval is just typedef to a double, so there is nothing to do in case of a float. No trouble at all... :)

```
        float t = 5;
        NSTimeInterval ti = t;
```

Cheers.